# Swift get UITextField placeholder label color

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to know what color is used for text field placeholder.
I have project that use default text field with default placeholder in many times. Also i need to implement UI elements that use custom placeholder label. Unfortunately, i can't find any information about color specification of UITextField placeholder.

Can someone provide RGB or HEX value for this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a screenshot and then use a color picker to determine the color.

Comment: @rmaddy i tried to but not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode can pick color from editor #_#

the color is very closed to Magnesium in Crayons panel of color picker,
hex is C7C7CD, Magnesium is C0C0C0, I like regular number, suggest you use C0C0C0 instead, really the same

Comment: Also keep in mind that the actual placholder text seems to be slightly transparent (see below).

Comment: that's the reason! xcode pick the color as Magnesium, but value is not C0C0C0,  because it is a Magnesium with alpha

Answer (score 4):

The [`attributedPlaceholder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619610-attributedplaceholder) property of `UITextField` is a `NSAttributedString`. Querying this string's `.foregroundColor` attribute yields `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0.0980392 0.22`.

So the color seems to be:

```swift
let color = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.0980392, alpha: 0.22)
```